# Getting error while running hive on windows

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting following error when I try to run hive on windows, my hadoop is running fine on windows:

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Beeline version 2.1.1 by Apache Hive
Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Connection is already closed.
```

Here is my hive-site.xml:

```
 <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
   <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hive</value>
<description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hivepwd</value>
<description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
 <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
 <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>
   <property>
  <name>hive.server2.enable.impersonation</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.script.wrapper</name>
    <value/>
    <description/>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.plan</name>
    <value/>
    <description/>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
 <value>True</value>
 </property>
```

Here is my hive-env.sh:

```
> export HADOOP_HOME=C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\hadoop-2.6.2 export
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
> HIVE_CONF_DIR=C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\hadoop-2.6.2\hive\apache-hive-2.1.1-bin\conf
```

mysql user is created and derbyclient.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar is placed in hive/bin/lib directory. Also I have created schema for my database by using SOURCE C:/Users/namaagarwal/Desktop/hadoop-2.6.2/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-txn-schema-2.0.0.mysql.sql;

I have searched a lot but didn't get any solution for this.

What am I missing??

Comment: have you used `schematool` yet? https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_command-line-installation/content/validate_installation.html

Comment: where I have to run this command ?? I am installing it on windows. I have tried running it in:

 C:\Users\namaagarwal\Desktop\hadoop-2.6.2\hive\apache-hive-2.1.1-bin\bin\schematool -initSchema -dbType mysql

But it is throwing following error:

The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: That error is from Windows, so is that your Hive folder? Is there a schematool (batch file) there?